# delegate respondsToSelector:selector not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I saw a lot of this kind of questions and answers here, but couldn't find solution to my problem. I'm trying to send data from one view controller to another and use delegate. But don't know why my postDelegate doesn't responds to selector. Is something wrong with this code or what is the problem?

PostViewController.h file

```
@protocol GetDataDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)getPassedInfo:(NSString*)info;

@end



@interface PostViewController : UIViewController 

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <GetDataDelegate> postDelegate;

@end;
```

PostViewController.m file

```
#import "PostViewController.h"

- (IBAction)postData:(id)sender {


if ([_postDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(getPassedInfo:)]) {

    [self.postDelegate getPassedInfo:@"data"];

    NSLog(@"responds");
}
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

in second view controllers .h file

```
#import "PostViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController : UITableViewController <GetDataDelegate>
```

and in .m file

```
@implementation MainWindowTableViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{   
 [super viewDidLoad];

 PostViewController * postController = [[PostViewController alloc]init];
 postController.postDelegate = self;
```

}

and here is delegate method:

```
 -(void)getPassedInfo:(NSString *)info{

    NSLog(@"info is %@", info);
 }
```

Comment: That local is going to be destroyed the second -viewDidLoad pops its frame off the stack.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make `postController` a property or an ivar. Currently it is a local variable in the `viewDidLoad` method which will be deallocated after `viewDidLoad` completes as @CodaFi said above.

```
#import "PostViewController.h"
@interface MainViewController : UITableViewController <GetDataDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) PostViewController *postController;

@end
```

Then:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{   
 [super viewDidLoad];

 self.postController = [[PostViewController alloc]init];
 self.postController.postDelegate = self;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that way but it doesn't work.. same result.

Comment: @andrey Hey, any luck with solving the problem? I've got the same issue.